# How to optimize events scheduling with unknown future events?

Tags: algorithm, logic, maximum-profit-problem

Scenario:

I need to give users opportunity to book different times for the service. 
Caveat is that i dont have bookings in advance but i need to fill them as they come in.

Bookings can be represented as keyvalue pairs:

`[startTime, duration]`

So, for example, `[9,3]` would mean event starts at 9 o’clock and has duration of 3 hours.

Rules:

- users come in one by one, there is never a batch of users requests
- no bookings can overlap
- service is available 24/7 so no need to worry about “working time”
- users choose `duration` on their own
- obviously, once user chooses&confirms his booking we cannot shuffle it anymore
- we dont want gaps to be lesser than some amount of time. this one is based on probability that future users will fill in the gap. for example, if distribution of `durations` over users bookings is such that probability for future users filling the gap shorter than `x` hours is less than `p` then we want a rule that gap cannot be shorter than `x`. (for purpose of this question, we can assume `x` being hardcoded, here i just explain reasons)
- the goal is to have service-busy-duration maximized

My thinking so far...

1. I keep the list of bookings made so far
2. I also keep track of gaps (as they are potential slots for new users booking)
3. When new user comes with his booking `[startTime, duration]` i first check for ideal case where `gapLength = duration`. if there is no such gaps, i find all slots (gaps) that satisfy condition `gapLength - duration > minimumGapDuration` and order them in descending order by that `gapLength - duration` value
4. I assign user to the first gap with maximum value of `gapLength - duration` since that gives me highest probability that gap remaining after this booking will also get filled in future

Questions:

1. Are there some problems with my approach that i am missing?
2. Are there some algorithms solving this particular problem?
3. Is there some usual approach (good starting point) which i could start with and optimize later? (i am actually trying to get enough infos to start but not making some critical mistake; optimizations can/should come later)

PS.
From research so far it sounds this might be the case for constraint programming. I would like to avoid it if possible as i have no clue about it (maybe its simple, i just dont know) but if it makes a real difference, i will go for its benefits and implement it.

I went through stackoverflow for similar problems but didnt find one with unknown future events. If there is such and this is direct duplicate, please refer to it.